# Spring and Hibernate messed up configuration files

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

From some time now I'm building an Spring 4.1.7.RELEASE/Hibernate 4.2.7.Final/Mysql 5.1.27/Tomcat7 webapp and all the time face some problems that are not really java code but rather configuration related. I just can't seem to understand those xml files and beans definitions... Today I was trying to use JPA to create repositories for my entities and I can't get rid of the problems although it's very simple code.

I'd really appreciate some help with understanding beans definition and in cleaning my .xml files.

The errors I'm getting and getting again:

```
**SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/root-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)V**

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:         org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)V**

SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext**
```

Here are my xml files for the project:

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
   <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing
          infrastructure -->

   <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
   <bean:annotation-driven />
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.runninglife.controller" />

   <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /web-resources/** by efficiently serving
          up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources/ directory -->
   <bean:resources mapping="/web-resources/**" location="/resources/" />

   <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources
          in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->

   <beans:bean
           class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
          <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
          <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </beans:bean>

    <!-- Apache Tiles Resolver & Config -->

<beans:bean id="tilesViewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="tilesConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-definitions.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

root-context.xml

```
<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

<!-- JPA Context for Repository -->
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.runninglife.repository" />

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
      destroy-method="close"
      p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
      p:url="${jdbc.url}"
      p:username="${jdbc.username}"
      p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
                <value>com.runninglife.entity.User</value>
        </list>
    </property>


    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.runninglife.*</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.runninglife" />
```

web.xml

```
<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets
     and Filters -->

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <!-- We can also use url-pattern like: *.html / *.htm / *.json etc. -->
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I can't find anywhere a solution to this problem.

Regards,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

After a horrible amount of research, I've got to the bottom of the problem.

Although the spring versions were kind of 'interfered' by the jpa-data dependency, the main confusion started in root-context.xml where I've misunderstood actual idea of the entityManagerFactory and used the hibernate sessionFactory whereas I tried to implement JPA-Hibernate approach with the: 
" org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ".

Nevertheless I'd put the correct root-context.xml content for those who might face the similar problem:

Starting with the component-scan with Controllers exclude (as they've should been in dispatcher servlet):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="GroupId of your Api">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

Using e.g HSQL for developer stadium usage:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database type="HSQL" id="dataSource"/>
```

And the rest and the most important jpa entity manager:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="PATH_TO_ENTITIES"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceProvider">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Transaction manager settings -->

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- JPA Context for Repository -->
<jpa:repositories base-package="PATH_TO_REPOSITORIES"
                  entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
                  transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>
```

Also there is a possible solution to the spring-version interference because of data-jpa. If someone does still have the problem put a:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Before your dependencies stack in pom.xml, and then of course don't forget to add the spring-boot-starter-data dependency.

That would be all.

Hope anyone find it useful.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with your dependencies. If you're not using a dependency management tool such a Maven I suggest you do. It's almost impossible to pull in the correct dependencies if you try to do it yourself.

If you are using a dependency management tool then make sure that all of the Spring jars on your classpath are the same version.

Comment: I'm using Maven ofcourse, the problem is probably trying to use JPA (when I'm adding to my dependencies spring-data-jpa, spring-jpa and aop - all of the newest versions it seems to crush tomcat server start with those Errors I've mentioned at the top).

Adding spring-data-jpa, spring-jpa and aop may be messing up with spring versions -> it does download some 'older' spring jars but if they're latest version how to use them with the newest spring version then? :/

I'm just stuck - never thought that It will be such a pain to just build some repositories that extends JPArepos...